# MVC datasets with viewbags

Tags: c#, html, sql, asp.net-mvc

**How do I put a dataset into a viewbag and display the result in a view?**

I have a dataset from a model that I write to a viewbag. I want to use a foreach loop to get the datarows out of the viewbag in the view.

**I already have a variable going into the view, so I cant pass the dataset normally. I will also have many other datasets per page. so I thought viewbag was the best way to approach this issue.**

model

```
class modeldata 
{
    public dataset readrows(DataSet dataset)
    {
    //returns data from sql query.
    }
}
```

controller:

```
 DataSet data = new DataSet();
 modeldata getdata = new modeldata ();
 ViewBag.Data = getdata.readrows(data);
 return view("page1") //based on case statement. 
 //Already have a value going into view, so I need to use viewbag
```

View:

```
@Model site.controllers.homecontroller;

     foreach (Model.data row in ViewBag.Data.Rows)
        {
            @:row["id"] + " " + row["name"];
        }
```

Comment: Why are you using DataSets in an MVC app?  Things work a lot better if you deal with data models and an ORM.

Comment: legacy code with 100's of SQL statements. Don't have time to convert for this project.

Comment: So, what is the actual question?

Comment: The question is: How do I put a dataset into a viewbag and display the rows in the view. I have a foreach example above.

Comment: Is the `foreach` example working? If not, what is not working? Looks like the code you've provided should work, assuming the type `Model.data` is the same as an item in `ViewBag.Data.Rows`. I think that might need to be `DataRow`, but it's been a while since I messed with DataSets.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To display data in the view, you have two options. One is to pass an instance of a Model class to a strongly-typed view. The second option is to use ViewBag. In your case, it looks like you are doing a little bit of both, but I would recommend using the strongly-typed view approach.

The View will have a `Model` property that represents an instance of the class type specified by your `@Model` declaration. In your code, you are using the controller class which is not going to work. I rewrote the example to use a `DataSet` as the model. As you can see, the `Model` property of the View becomes an instance of the `System.Data.DataSet` class and has all of its properties and methods.

**View**

```
@Model System.Data.DataSet;

foreach (DataRow row in Model.Rows)
{
    @:row["id"] + " " + row["name"];
}
```

**Controller**

```
DataSet data = new DataSet();
modeldata getdata = new modeldata();
return View(getdata.readrows(data));
```

**Edit:**

Here is an example that uses a Dictionary in the model class to store multiple DataSets. You can then modify the View to use the modeldata type as its Model class.

**Model**

```
namespace Site.Models
{
    class modeldata
    {
        public Dictionary<string, DataSet> DataSets { get; set; }

        public static DataSet ReadRows(DataSet dataset)
        {
            //returns data from sql query.
        }
    }
}
```

**View**

```
@Model Site.Models.modeldata;

@foreach (System.Data.DataTable table in Model.DataSets["sampleData"].Tables)
{
    foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        @:row["id"] + " " + row["name"];
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
DataSet data = new DataSet();
modeldata getdata = new modeldata();
getdata.DataSets["sampleData"] = modeldata.ReadRows(data);
return View(getdata);
```

Comment: I have something else going into the view, and I plan to have multiple datasets per page so I cant return it. Is there another way to reach it from the view?

Comment: @user719825: Just create a ViewModel class that has both the "something else" you want to send to the view *and* the dataset. That way a single object can fulfill both needs.

Comment: Hmmm that is really an interesting approach. Could you provide me an example?

Comment: I edited my answer to show this. you can create properties in the `modeldata` class to store the other data you need.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I am still working on this. I think the only problem I have with this example is .Rows still doesn't exist in the foreachloop because "DataSets" is a property. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: @user719825 Sorry, i hadn't actually tried the code. If you are using DataSet, you have to iterate over its `Tables` collection first, and then get the rows from each `DataTable`. I edited my answer to show this.

Comment: Using `@:` in the view prints out the text verbatim, so would print `row["id"] + " " + row["name"];` on the page.  I think you mean `@row["id"]` where you want to print the id field.

Comment: @tdjfdjdj `Could you provide me an example?` You could also try to use a [Tuple](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple(v=vs.110).aspx)`<int,decimal,date,dataset>` opposed to a `Dictionary`

Answer (score 1):

You would need to create a model class to contain each dataset as a property, e.g:

```
public class MyModel 
{
    DataSet data1,
    DataSet data2,
    DataSet data3
}
```

Then return a strongly typed view bound to the type '`MyModel`' which in the view would then allow you to do:

```
var myDataInTheView = model.data1;
```

You can then use the foreach approach as others have described, but on the properties of the model, rather than the model class itself. In the snippet above, loop over `myDataInTheView`