# Replacing EF4.1 with ADO.net when calling stored proc in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, stored-procedures, ado.net

I need to replace EF4.1 with ADO.NET. The data in our application is returned by stored procedures only. I need help re-writing calls like the following (in order to write a DAL for the application):

**EF calling stored procedure:**

```
using (var db = new NexGenContext())
{
   SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@ReviewID", Id);
   var issues = db.Database.SqlQuery<QuestionIssue>(
        "SP_GetQuestionIssues @ReviewID", param).ToList();

   return View(issues);
}
```

What is the equivalent in ADO.NET? Get data from the database and map to my models?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest ADO.NET technology to being an ORM without actually crossing the line is data sets. Data sets act very much like an ORM in the way you can access data directly from a table without looping through a cursor. Data Sets return lists directly and can track new data vs old.

This link is a pretty good overview:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/718fc8/working-with-dataset-in-ado-net/

This [MVC datasets with viewbags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9824531/mvc-datasets-with-viewbags) stack thread specifically addresses using Data Sets in Models.

Comment: I guess you I can do something like: public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var data = _repository.GetInvoicesDataSet();
        return View(data);
    }

Comment: But, deosn't the view require a model? What do I declare on top of the view?

Comment: the view does require a model. It is common to use 'entities' as models. I find it to be a good start, but limiting. In this case you would declare a model in a class library in the Models folder. Something like Public InvoicesModel{ IEnumberable<Invoices> InvoiceList}

Comment: In your action method you would instantiate InvoicesModel Model = new InvoicesModel(); InvoicesModel.InvoiceList = DS.Invoices([WhereClause]);

Comment: Thank you for the explaination.

Comment: Chaka, i found this stack thread specifically discussing best way to use data sets in models. I'll edit my answer to include it.